# Extracting slopes by categorical variable from a new data frame?

Tags: r, gradient, lm

I have a data set depicting the BMI change for 199 countries over the span of 38 years (1980 to 2008). The data was originally in a wide format, and I (thought I) tidied it up:

```
BMI <- read.csv("Indicator_BMI female ASM.csv", header = TRUE)
BMI2 <- gather(BMI, "year", "BMI", X1980:X2008)
BMI2$year <- as.numeric(BMI2$year)
BMI <- BMI2
```

until it ended up in this format:

```
Country          Year       BMI
Afghanistan     X1980      20.443
Afghanistan     X1981      20.477      
Afghanistan     X1982      20.523  
...
Albania         X1980      25.174
Albania         X1981      25.191 
.......
Algeria         X1980      20.241
.....
```

etc, you get the idea..

What I want to do is, for each country to get the gradient of the slope of the relationship between Year and BMI.

First I tried very simply to extract the slope for one country at a time:

```
thefit <- lm(BMI ~ year, subset(BMI, Country == "Albania"))
gradientAlbania <- round(coef(thefit)[2],4)
```

but the output from the lm alone is quite unexpected (only intercepts for each year separately):

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)    yearX1981    yearX1982    yearX1983    yearX1984    yearX1985    yearX1986    yearX1987    yearX1988    yearX1989    yearX1990  
   25.17427      0.01661      0.02605      0.04479      0.04932      0.03830      0.03512      0.01491     -0.00462     -0.02057     -0.03550  
  yearX1991    yearX1992    yearX1993    yearX1994    yearX1995    yearX1996    yearX1997    yearX1998    yearX1999    yearX2000    yearX2001  
   -0.12757     -0.20812     -0.23869     -0.23865     -0.23721     -0.20784     -0.20673     -0.17207     -0.11173     -0.04630      0.02905  
  yearX2002    yearX2003    yearX2004    yearX2005    yearX2006    yearX2007    yearX2008  
    0.09655      0.15771      0.22377      0.29098      0.35901      0.41967      0.48299
```

I guess it has to do with the format of the data frame (like the X in front of the year that I couldn't get rid off..)
Although I successfully created a BMI~year scatter plot for this data, by country, so I assumed in principle the format should be ok?

[BMI year scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLwPF.png)

Thanks for the help in advance. 
In case it matters, later I want to include a slope function as part of the dplyr group_by, but this will come in a separate post (I decided to break down the question in different posts for clarity).

Comment: Since your years start with "X" they'll be read as character variables instead of numeric variables.  If there is no "X" outside of R, the function you used to read the data in made syntactically valid names (in `read_table()` this default can be turned off via`check.names = FALSE`).  So you could suppress the "X" being added and then use `convert = TRUE` in `gather()`.  Alternatively you could remove the "X" after gathering.  For this the function `readr::parse_number()` might work well in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As @aosmith mentioned, you need to get rid of those "X"s.

Does this do work on your data and accomplish what you want:

```
BMI <- read.csv("Indicator_BMI female ASM.csv", header = TRUE)
BMI2 <- gather(BMI, "year", "BMI", X1980:X2008)
BMI2$year <- as.numeric(gsub('X',"",BMI2$year))

# Adapted from "R for Data Science"

country_model <- function(df){
  lm(BMI~year, data = df)
}

BMI2 %>%
  group_by(country) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, country_model)) %>% 
  mutate(slope = model[[1]][[1]][[2]])
```